# Returning a double value but with a trailing zero at the end

Tags: java

```
Double d = 10.30
```

When I use this value of d i.e `10.30` it becomes `10.3`

Is there anyway that I can sustain this value of `10.30`
Remember I cannot change the data-type it should be a double

Is there a way??

Comment: Of course there is. You need to explain first where/how you want to "sustain" it. Is it to show in the console/panel or whatever?

Comment: That's a print detail, not a numerical detail.  Ten and three-tenths is the same as ten and thirty-hundredths, so there's really no incentive/reason for the data type to keep track of that information which space is already at a very high premium.  If you want to *display* a trailing zero, that's another matter altogether.

Comment: Yes this double value is going to be displayed in the frontend side. The thing is I can add an extra zero in the JavaScript side by the toFixed() method,but there are numerous places where I have to make the change. If I could just figure out a way to have a 10.20 value is a double , that would be awesome

Answer (score 2):

A double only contains only information about the value it represents, but not about the precision of it.

Whether a double is represented as `10.3`, `10.30`, `10.300000` etc. is determined by the display resp. string conversion routine, not by the routine which generates the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with Double class.

If you want to display a value with zero you could do this:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```

It means that your variable `d` will be displayed with 2 digits after point. So, if `d = 10.3`, the code above will show `10.30`

String also can store formatted value:

```
String s = String.format("%.2f%n", d);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Yeah but then the data-type will change. If I cast back the 10.40 to double it will be as before i.e 10.4 which I don't want in my case.

Comment: But it make no sense how it looks in double. While you are doing math operations, for example, 10.3 is the same as you would use 10.30. But if you want to show this number to user, ok, probably it makes sense to format a number only  while displaying.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is

private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

df.format(amountDouble)